# How to clear UserDefaults for Xcode build of Mac app?

Tags: xcode, macos, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to make sure my first-run code works properly, and so I'd like to clear the preferences file created by `UserDefaults.standard.set` calls. Where is it located, or is there at least a way to clear it out (other than writing it into my app)?

Running **Product > Clean** does not clear out the defaults.

I've looked in DerivedData, ~/Library/Preferences, /Library/Preferences, and haven't found what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the app is sandboxed the preferences are located in

```
~/Library/Containers/[bundle-identifier]/Data/Library/Preferences
```

If it's not sandboxed the preferences are at the usual location

```
~/Library/Preferences
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a Big Sur change, but I found that I had to additionally kill the `cfprefsd` process after deleting the property list. The alternative would be to use Andrew's approach, but this doesn't seem to remove the property list, rather, it empties it.

Comment: For a MacOS app running under Catalina, preferences are in a hidden Library/Preferences folder in User home folder named [bundle-identifier].plist. However, renaming this file does not prevent the application from using values are in it. It seems as though the preferences values are cached and persist even when the user logs out and in again. Restarting clears it. Does killing `cprefsd` have the same effect as restarting?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `defaults` command In Terminal

```
$ defaults delete com.bundle.identifier
```

Also you can delete any value in defaults by key, if you don't want to delete whole application defaults plist.

```
$ defaults delete com.bundle.identifier kSomeKey
```

Comment: This command seems to clear the cache as well and is much easier than restarting

Comment: `defaults` does not work for sandboxed apps.  See the answer below for that situation.